# Backup strategy for build tool hosted on Azure VM

Tags: linux, build, backup, teamcity, azure-virtual-machine

We are hosting TeamCity (Continunos Integration) and Atlassian Jira and Confluence tools in the same Azure VM with Linux Ubuntu (LTS 14.04) as OS.

As all the tools reside on the same VM, would a periodic VM backup be the best approach to backup them? Or rather implement a tool specific approach would be better? 
As example, considering Team City, it is suggested to call its REST API to run the backup.But this requires to write little apps for each tools, while the VM backup would take them all in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

VM snapshot is easy to manage and easy to restore, but you have the risk of losing whole data in case of corruption. Take a periodic backup of all your applications from Azure to local infrastructure but keep a snapshot for quick recovery.

Comment: Thanks Ram for the answer. This approach would have more reliability, but on the other side it would add double overhead (VM snapshots plus individual backups).

Comment: @Luca. Those are two options and you have to choose between them or both of them depending on your application and it's importance. If you don't mind interruptions to your applications, backups is cheaper and reliable option. If you want quick point-in-time recovery snapshots is the way. Two is the best of both worlds.

Comment: I decided to go for the VM snapshot, as the backup is only for saving the config files of our build tools. So no critical customer data. Thanks for the point.